Raspberry Pi 5 with module 3 camera Device timeout detected, attempting a restart!!! Error
Hello I have Raspberry Pi 5 and picamera module 3. I am using my camera without any problem nearly 2 months. But yesterday my camera gives an error and shows a black image:

I bought and tried with new cable but its not solved.
Can you help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
